# How to change text size of drawer menu title?

Tags: android

I try to find the answer that set a style and use it for drawer layout , just like this:

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

But it only change the menu item , i want to change it for title
Here is my drawer menu setting:

```
<item android:title="@string/evaluationTools">//I want to change it 
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/evaluation"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_icon_app_96x96"
            android:title="@string/evaluation" />//not this
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dataReport"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_icon_data_96x96"
            android:title="@string/dataReport" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Any ideas ?  Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added **app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"**  in "<item android:title="@string/evaluationTools">"

Comment: I added the style in my drawer layout xml

Answer (score 0):

Try at the start or at some point of the text command line

```
<text><h2>Test text</h2></text>
```

The higher the number is on the h"2" the smaller its going to get...
h1 is the biggest and so forth.

Good luck if it does not work please comment back

Comment: Thanks for your responding , but where should i put the code `<text><h2>Test text</h2></text>` ?

Comment: sorry for the very long dellay :( ... if you are still looking for an answer may i ask what type of software you are useing? Sorry and i hope you find your answer, thanks

Comment: It's fine dude , i had improved my issue , thanks for your enthusiasm.